# Uninstalling macOS App Extensions from System Preferences

Tags: macos, applications, system-settings

I'm a developer, but it is more of a user-centric question.

How can one "unregister" a Finder Sync (or any other, presumably) OS X / macOS App Extension so that it disappears from System Preferences > Extensions?

I've removed the app that's hosting it (FinderSyncTest), but it still shows here:

[image: How to remove 10.10 Application Extension]

Answer (score 5):

I found my extensions in:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ShareKit.framework/Versions/A/PlugIns
```

Delete FinderSyncTest.appex, restart Finder, and it should be gone.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case here.

Comment: Try running "locate FinderSyncTest" from Terminal. Good chance you'll find where the extensions are located.

Comment: It didn't work for me for my project..... Any other way to find?

Answer (score 4):

Did you create this extension yourself?

I found that after creating, building, and testing an extension I created that there was some data that lives here:

```
/Users/$USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

that I needed to blow away and then relaunch the Finder (which can be done with Force Quit) to get the extension to "die"

Comment: Yes I created my own, but it does't exist there, I removed all the files in DerivedData, but still see whole bunch of extensions.

Answer (score 3):

Another answer in addition to my previous one: if your extension is actually runnable (i.e.: it doesn't crash when started via System Preferences -> Extensions), find the extension in your Activity Monitor, double click the process, then go to the "Open Files and Ports" tab. You'll see the path of your extension listed.

Answer (score 2):

I found my location via the `"Open Files and Ports"` location in Activity Monitor mentioned in the other answer.

This lead to the location:

`/Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2018-10-09/MyApp 10-9-18, 9.35 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/MyAppFinderSync.appex/Contents/MacOS/MyAppFinderSync`

This archive was 10 days old and I'm not sure why it would have been running. I've been deleting my app since that date, and I believe the extension was being removed from System Preferences.

I deleted the archives in that location, and the app extension no longer runs (which it was doing before). However, it's still listed in System Preferences. Still looking for a way to fully delete.

Edit: I started running a new version of the container app, from `/Applications/`. About 10 minutes later, I went back to System Preferences and toggled the Extension on/off and back to on. This launched the new version of the Extension and everything appears to now be working normally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove it from **DerivedData** and restart the finder.
I use **DevCleaner**, a free utility on the app store to deal with that:

[image: screenshot of devcleaner]