# How to locate extensions in list of macOS system settings?

Tags: macos, system-settings, plugins, file-extensions

I am working on a macOS file provider extension. Sometimes it cannot register itself (or more precisely its file provider domains) correctly due to some XPC issues with the `NSFileProviderManager`. Then I try to get a clean environment again.

1. I completely erased Xcode's DerivedData.
2. I emptied the trash because macOS does not care about the locations in this regard and loads extensions from there, too.
3. I removed all of the extensions file provider domains from the side bar in Finder.

Looking for my extension in pluginkit yields no results by running this command:

```sh
$ pluginkit -vvvvmi <redacted-bundle-identifier>
  (no matches)
```

It also does not appear in the full list when leaving out the explicit identifier specification. **Still it appears in the list of the system settings! Where does this come from and how to reset it?** I can enable and disable them in the system settings. They even survive a reboot. And in macOS' Console.app I continuously see entries about the file providers displayed as "SomeProduct" and "Provider" here along their bundle identifiers. It appears like I messed up `fileproviderd`.

[image: system settings screenshot]

I considered this more appropriate for this StackExchange site rather than StackOverflow because it is not directly related to programming. Also [these answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/152541/58460) unfortunately did contain a solution. I also wrote a feedback in feedback assistant but according to my experience that is unlikely to be heard.